# What is the purpose of FeedReaderContract and how to define inner class in OpenHelper Class

Tags: android, sqlite

I am learning SQLite in android. For SQLite I am reffering developer.android.com. But I got some Confusion while reading the code. They wrote `FeedReaderContract` constructor to prevent 
instantiating the `FeedReaderContract` class but they don't define `FeedReaderContract` class anywhere and the relation between `FeedReaderContract` and `FeedEntry`.

[Here's link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DbHelper) which I am referring to. I provide code. How can I define inner class in openhelper class. Could anybody suggest me the good way?.

For example, this snippet defines the table name and column names for a single table:

```
public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns 
{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
    ...
}
```

To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class, give it an empty constructor.

```
 //Prevents the FeedReaderContract class from being instantiated.
private FeedReaderContract() {}
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. What code do you want explained? The code in the article you linked is explained in the article. (For example, the article describes the first code section you quoted, "this snippet defines the table name and column names for a single table". What more would you want to know?)

Comment: I have provided some meaning to your question title. Feel free to rollback, if it doesnt suites your question.

Answer (score 4):

I understand as:

```
public static class FeedReaderContract{

    // Prevents the FeedReaderContract class from being instantiated.
    private FeedReaderContract() {} 

    //The FeedEntry table definition
    public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
        ...
    }

    //more tables definition
}
```

So you can't instatiate the contract but can access all the inner classes Constants. Like the example line:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
"CREATE TABLE " + FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," //continues
```

Access the `FeedEntry` constants (`TABLE_NAME` and `_ID`) of the inner class in `FeedReaderContract` class.

Hope it helps.