# How can someone accidentally initiate a class in Java?

Tags: java, android, class, instantiation

I was reading the android tutorial and I come accross this code:

```
public final class FeedReaderContract {
    // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
    // give it an empty constructor.
    public FeedReaderContract() {}

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
         public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
         public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
         public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
         public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
         ...
    }
}
```

Here's the link to the tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DbHelper

Though I have worked on Java previously, I do not understand how one could accidentally initiate a class in Java. How could this be possible?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354369/what-is-the-purpose-of-feedreadercontract-and-how-to-define-inner-class-in-openh) is not what I am looking for.

Comment: this mean you shouldnt instantiate the class like trying to instantiate without knowing it shouldn't be instantiate

Comment: If it's to prevent the class from being instantiated, the *constructor* should be **`private`**.

Comment: That statement literally makes no sense.

Comment: the contract should contain only constants. With this in mind, an instance is superfluous. To prevent the creation of the object, they add the empty constructor. Unfortunately they failed with the `public` access specifier

Comment: yes constructor should be private

Comment: Yes. This was just stupid of me to not notice. Thanks all. :)

Comment: @Blackbelt: I guess my question was different. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's meant to be private, eg:

```
private FeedReaderContract() {}
```

This would make it impossible for a developer to instantiate a FeedReaderContract instance

Comment: It is not. Because in itself this class would not have any use. So there has to be a public constructor.

Comment: That's incorrect. This is often done for classes that only have static methods. Eg [Assert](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html)

Comment: @user2520215 it is a mistake in the "documentation"

Comment: @Lance Yes. I though I did not post that comment. Now I appear dumber. :P

Comment: @Blackbelt: Yes, thank you. :)